# CSS: How can I hide a class which has no other class or ID?

Tags: class, css

So how can I had a td which has only 1 class?

For example:

```
<td class="ss_label ss_class">Hello</td>
<td class="ss_label">World!</td>
```

I this case I want to `display:none` the second one.

This works: `$('[class="ss_label"]').hide();` but **I don't want to use Javascript or any library such as jQuery**. Just pure CSS.

In the real life example, the td I want to hide is the sixth and seventh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use that [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) from jQuery in CSS as well:

```
td[class="ss_label"] { display: none }
```

This will match a `<td>` element whose class attribute is *exactly* "ss_label" with no other additions to it. Works in all major browsers except IE6 (if you consider it a major browser).

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
.ss_label { display: none }
.ss_label.ss_class { display: table-cell }
```

for this specific case.

As far as I know, there is no general solution.

Comment: even though this is the correct answer for the question asked, i doubt this is what he really wants to know :P i mean this is basic css, no basic doesnt even cut it....

Comment: @Breezer, I explicitly said, "As far as I know, there is no general solution."

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style type="text/css">
.ss_label {
display:none;
}
.ss_label.ss_class {
display:block;
}
</style>
```

The last rule overrides the first one

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the attribute selector (works in safari)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div.hide { color: green   }
      div[class=hide] { display: none }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hide">Hide me</div>
    <div class="no hide">Don't hide me</div>
  </body>
</html>
```